# Exporting a Scikit Learn Random Forest for use on Hadoop Platform

Tags: python, hadoop, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pmml

I've developed a spam classifier using pandas and scikit learn to the point where it's ready for integration into our hadoop-based system.  To this end, I need to export my classifier to a more common format than pickling.

The Predictive Model Markup Language (PMML) is my preferred export format.  It plays exceedingly well with Cascading, which we already use.  However, I surprisingly cannot find any python libraries that export scikit-learn models into PMML.

Has anyone had experience with this use case?  Is there any sort of alternative to PMML that would lend interoperability between scikit-learn and hadoop?  What about a solid PMML export library?

Comment: there's a similar question over at Quora http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-scikit-learn-with-Hadoop-and-Mapreduce

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Using the streaming API is not ideal, but I may have to resort to it if all else fails.

Comment: Spam classification as in email spam? How did you come to use a Random Forest for that?

Comment: Actually in this case, it's microblog spam where we are targeting only  a subset of all machine-generated messages.  The relative variety of features seems to play nice with random forest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [Py2PMML](https://support.zementis.com/entries/37092748-Introducing-Py2PMML) to export the model to PMML and then evaluate it on Hadoop using [JPMML-Cascading](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-cascading). JPMML is open source but Py2PMML from Zementis seems to be a commercial product. Besides this alternative there are no other tools to score Scikit models exported as PMML on Java/Hadoop. The core scikit team is [planning](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1596) to implement a PMML exporter though. But if you don't want any commercial solutions or wait for such tool to be implemented you still have some options but they require some coding:

- Adapt the [SKLearn Compiled trees](https://github.com/ajtulloch/sklearn-compiledtrees) project so it generates Java/MapReduce code instead of C.
- Using the `export_graphviz`function obtain the DOT representation of each decision tree and write a small Java interpreter.
- Forget about Java and Hadoop, use Apache Spark and evaluate each one of the decision trees in parallel using Python, Scikit and PySpark.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The export of SkLearn models to PMML can be handled by the JPMML-SkLearn (https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn) library/command-line application now. It is much more robust and easier to work with than Py2PMML.